# how do I create a type of fixed-length array in Typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, react-tsx

I'm using typescript and I want to have a type that has a property that is an array. but I want to make the array fixed length, is that possible?

what I mean is :

```
//example code , not my actual case but similar
export type Car = {
  doors:Door[];//here I want it to be exactly 4 doors
  /// rest of code
}
```

I tried doing this :

```
export type Pattern = {
  doors: Array<Door>[4];
  ////
};
```

but that made doors `(property) doors: Door` instead of an array of 4 `Door` objects.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both `Javascript` and `typescript` you can create a fix size `Array` using `new` keyword.

**Like this:**

```
  let arr: number[] = new Array(3);
```

**But,** in your situation you can use **`tuple type`** to do this.

#### Example

```
export type Car = {
  doors: [Door, Door, Door, Door];
};

// Usage
let car: Car = {
  doors: [
    // fill array
  ]
};
```

#### Javascript Example

```js
const arr = new Array (3);

arr [0] = 'door1'
arr [1] = 'door2'
arr [2] = 'door3'

console.log (arr.length)
```